# SQL Server Selecting Multiple Rows based on minimum dates and two other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATE:
Here's my actual query: This query works perfectly if I set an employee id in the inner select (the commented out where clause). If, however, I take that employee ID out in an attempt to run this for ALL employee’s, it selects (almost) all dates for that employee.

```
SELECT* FROM ( 
    SELECT id, shop_id, local_id, employee_id, invoice_date, 
    LAG(shop_id)OVER(ORDER BY invoice_date) as new_Col1, 
    LAG(local_id)OVER(ORDER BY invoice_date) as new_Col2 
    FROM tmpMemPayment 
) as A 
WHERE NOT( (shop_id = ISNULL(new_Col1,'')) 
           and (local_id = ISNULL(new_Col2,'')) )
```

----END UPDATE

I am trying for a complicated query and can get close but not quite close enough. I've tried partitions but still no joy.

What I'm trying:

MyTable:
    Col1    Col2    Date

```
x        y      1/1/2018
x        y      1/1/2017
x        z      1/1/2016
x        y      1/1/2015
a        b      1/1/2014
a        b      1/1/2013
x        y      1/1/2012
```

I need each row with the minimum date within each partition where a partition is defined by col1 and col2 being the same for a set of continuous dates
i.e. the resultset I need is:

```
x    y    1/1/2017
x    z    1/1/2016
x    y    1/1/2015
a    b    1/1/2013
x    y    1/1/2012
```

Closest I've gotten is:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, min(t1.date)
from
MyTable t1
and t1.Date < 
(
select max(t2.Date) from MyTable t2 where 
(t2.col1 !=t1.col1 or t2.col2 != t1.col2)
)
group by col1, col2

union 


select t1.col1, t1.col2, min(t1.date)
from
MyTable t1
and t1.Date > 
(
select min(t2.Date) from MyTable t2 
where (t2.col1 !=t1.col1 or t2.col2 != t1.col2)
)
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: what is the logic you want ? why are the 1ste and 5th row not in your resultset ?

Comment: Ah, thanks for asking and sorry that wasn't clear. I need each row with the minimum date within each partition where a partition is defined by col1 and col2 being the same for a set of continuous dates.

Comment: What do you want to do????  Posting a broken query without telling us what you want won't help us help you!!!

Comment: Apologies, GuidoG also correctly dinged me here. I've edited.

Comment: @user621713 Just curious if you have checked my answer and if there is any issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD()` function to compare current row's values to the next row's values:

```
;with cte as (select 
                    *
                  , LEAD(Col1, 1) over (ORDER BY DT desc) as Col1_Next 
                  , LEAD(Col2, 1) over (ORDER BY DT desc) as Col2_Next 
              from MyTable)

select Col1, Col2, DT from cte
where Col1 <> ISNULL(Col1_Next, '') OR Col2 <> ISNULL(Col2_Next, '')
```

Working sample here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6650/5)

More info on [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 'x' as Col1, 'y' as Col2, '1/1/2018' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' as Col1, 'y' as Col2, '1/1/2017' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' as Col1, 'z' as Col2, '1/1/2016' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' as Col1, 'y' as Col2, '1/1/2015' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' as Col1, 'b' as Col2, '1/1/2014' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' as Col1, 'b' as Col2, '1/1/2013' as Date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' as Col1, 'y' as Col2, '1/1/2012' as Date

)
--Actual query  
SELECT col1,col2,Date FROM 
(
   SELECT col1, col2, [Date], LAG(Col1)OVER(ORDER BY [DATE]) as new_Col1, LAG(Col2)OVER(ORDER BY [DATE]) as new_Col2
   FROM CTE
) as A
WHERE NOT(
          (col1 = ISNULL(new_Col1,'')) and (col2 = ISNULL(new_Col2,''))
         )
```

Comment: So in the actual example I have a foreign key to an employee table and many of these combinations and dates for each employee. If I pass an employee ID into the inner select, this works great. If I run it across the entire table, it returns almost all of the  combinations/dates. I tried running it in a cursor but over a 52mil record table it would just take days.

Comment: Here's my actual query:
     
This query works perfectly if I set an employee id in the inner select (the commented out where clause).  If, however, I take that employee ID out in an attempt to run this for ALL employee’s, it selects (almost) all dates for that employee.

     SELECT*
FROM 
(
   SELECT id, shop_id, local_id, employee_id, invoice_date, 
   LAG(shop_id)OVER(ORDER BY invoice_date) as new_Col1, 
   LAG(local_id)OVER(ORDER BY invoice_date) as new_Col2
   FROM tmpMemPayment
) as A
WHERE NOT(
 (shop_id = ISNULL(new_Col1,'')) and (local_id = ISNULL(new_Col2,''))
 )

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `lag()`.  Here is one method:

```
select col1, col2, date
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(date) over (partition by col1, col2 order by date) as prev_date_2
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is null or prev_date <> prev_date_2;
```

The advantage of this method over using `lag()`s on the columns is that it is easily extensible to any number of columns -- they just go in the `partition by` clause, rather than generating an addition column and additional conditions in the `where` clause.